# GraphQL enum to DB integers instead of strings

Tags: database, performance, enums, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using GraphQL enum type like this:

```
enum PlayerSkill {
  happiness
  game
  run
  water
}
```

Can I store value instead of string in my DB?

Is it better to store integers instead of strings in DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value property when defining the enum in JavaScript. The example in the [graphql-js documentation](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlenumtype) should be very helpful. In Apollo you can achieve the same using [internal values](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums.html#internal-values) if you prefer the SDL approach.